# How do I delete files in hdfs directory after reading it using scala?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I use fileStream to read files in the hdfs directory from Spark (streaming context). In case my Spark shut down and starts after some time, I would like to read the new files in the directory. I don't want to read old files in the directory which was already read and processed by Spark. I am trying to avoid duplicates here.

```
val lines = ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat]("/home/File")
```

any code snippets to help?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the `FileSystem` API:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}

val fs = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)

val outPutPath = new Path("/abc")

if (fs.exists(outPutPath))
  fs.delete(outPutPath, true)
```

Answer (score 1):

`fileStream` already handles that for you - from its [Scaladoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext@fileStream[K,V,F%3C:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat[K,V]](directory:String)(implicitevidence$4:scala.reflect.ClassTag[K],implicitevidence$5:scala.reflect.ClassTag[V],implicitevidence$6:scala.reflect.ClassTag[F]):org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream[(K,V)]):

> Create an input stream that monitors a Hadoop-compatible filesystem for new files and reads them using the given key-value types and input format.

This means that `fileStream` would only load **new files** (created after streaming context was started), any files that already existed in the folder before you started your streaming application would be ignored.

Comment: I am trying to explain about fault tolerance here. Say I have number of  files 1 to 10 in hdfs and spark streaming has read this file. Now my spark streaming has stopped unfortunately. I have files in hdfs say 1 to 20 where 1 to 10 files were already parsed by spark streaming and 11 to 20 were added newly. Now I start spark streaming, I can see files 1- 30. Since I started spark at the time of 21st file in hdfs, My spark styreaming will loose files 11-20. how do I get lost files.