# Delete a csv file from scala

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I am trying to delete a csv file from scala I have tried this but it doesn't work, it doesn't delete the file; `result` is a dataset/dataframe:

```
result.withColumn("features", stringify(result.col("features")))
      .write
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .option("header","true")
      .csv("data/temporaryBasis")
...
    new File("data/temporaryBasis").delete()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you clarify your question: you want to delete a file on HDFS from a Spark application?

Comment: Yes, that is what i want to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I delete files in hdfs directory after reading it using scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45104284/how-do-i-delete-files-in-hdfs-directory-after-reading-it-using-scala)

Comment: not exactly, this is how I read my cvs file: var data=spark.read.csv("data/dataset")